# QueryContainerDescriptor vs QueryContainer vs QueryBase

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Can anyone explain what is the difference between *QueryContainerDescriptor*,  *QueryContainer* & *QueryBase*?

How can I assign a query (or *QueryBase*) to *QueryContainer*?

In the code below, I can assign the same *TermQuery* to *QueryBase* and *QueryContainer* objects:

```
QueryBase bq = new TermQuery
{
    Field = Field<POCO>(p => p.Title),
    Value = "my_title"
};

QueryContainer tq = new TermQuery
{
    Field = Field<POCO>(p => p.Title),
    Value = "my_title"
};
```

Also I am not sure if there is any difference between, creating a *TermQuery* using *QueryContainerDescriptor* and the above method?

```
QueryContainer qcd = new QueryContainerDescriptor<POCO>().
    Term(r => r.Field(f => f.Title).Value("my_title"));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `QueryBase` is the base type for all concrete query implementations
- `QueryContainer` is a container for a query. It is used in places where a query is expected.
- `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>` is a type for building a `QueryContainer` using a builder / fluent interface pattern.

NEST supports both an Object Initializer syntax where requests can be composed through instantiating types and composing an object graph by assigning types to properties, and also a Fluent API syntax, where requests can be composed using Lambda expressions and a fluent interface pattern. All `*Descriptor` types within NEST are builders for the Fluent API syntax. Use whichever syntax you prefer, or mix and match as you see fit :)

You might be thinking, why do we need `QueryContainer`, why not just use `QueryBase`? Well, within the JSON representation, a query JSON object is keyed against the name of the query as a property of an outer *containing* JSON object i.e.

```
{
  "query": { // <-- start of outer containing JSON object
    "term": { // <-- start of JSON query object
      "field": {
        "value": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Relating back to C# types, `QueryBase` will be serialized to the query JSON object and `QueryContainer` will be the outer *containing* JSON object. To make it easier to compose queries, there are implicit conversions from `QueryBase` to `QueryContainer`, so often you just need to instantiate a derived `QueryBase` implementation and assign it to a property of type `QueryContainer`

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var termQuery = new TermQuery
{
    Field = "field",
    Value = "value"
};

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<MyDocument>
{
    Query = termQuery // <-- Query property is of type QueryContainer
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(searchRequest);
```

With `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>`, you often don't need to instantiate an instance outside of the client call, as an instance will be instantiated within the call. Here's the same request with the Fluent API

```
client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term("field", "value")
    )
);
```